# nvm-windows fails when the user profile path contains a space

Tags: node.js, nvm-windows

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>nvm list

    6.7.0
  * 5.12.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)

C:\Windows\system32>nvm use 5.12.0
```

When I run this command, it shows this message:

```
exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Mehjabin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can fix this?

Comment: Are you using `nvm-windows`?

Comment: yes i am use nvm-windows

Comment: hey have you fixed it?

Comment: yes.I fixed it a years of ago @ReyYoung

Answer (score 15):

Try this

1. Create a folder in C: (just name it as **nodejs-root**) (it doesn't matter what name you give), then create one more folder in it (name it as **nvm**)
2. now run this command in cmd

   `nvm root C:\nodejs-root\nvm`

   `nvm install latest`

   `nvm use 14.4.0`

(in my case as of 14th June 2020 latest is 14.4.0) hence I did nvm use 14.4.0

At this stage, you might have got an error as

**elevate.cmd  missing(or something of that sort)**

just navigate to the location where nvm was initially installed 
in my case: `C:\Users\Sufyan Parkar\AppData\Roaming\nvm`

copy these 2 files from that folder

1. elevate.cmd
2. elevate.vbs

and paste it into the newly created folder located at `C:\nodejs-root\nvm`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Completely solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: great it works, but it is not showing already installed node versions

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the problem also. I use windows 10 O.S. When I first installed nvm to my machine, it worked smoothly. After reboot my machine seemed not to recognize nvm.

I did my research and opened settings.txt in the nvm folder located at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm. I copied the nvm path. I went and added the path to my environment variables.

I opened cmd again and tried to run nvm and this time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the default nvm path is added to your system path (tip - Windows key > search for 'environment variables' > select 'edit the system environment variables'. Make sure there is an entry like this (if you selected the default nvm install location):

```
C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\nvm\
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a space in the users home directory then nvm is not working and it is throwing the error that is mentioned above. Please modify the home directory to remove the space and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your windows terminal, run this command:
`cmd /c for %A in ("C:\Users\{Your profileName with spaces}\AppData\Roaming\nvm")`

For example:

> cmd /c for %A in ("C:\Users\Light Seeker\AppData\Roaming\nvm")
> Output:
> C:\Users\LIGHTS~1\AppData\Roaming\nvm

And then modify the settings.txt, which is found in the path where the nvm was installed. For this example, it is located in C:\Users\Light Seeker\AppData\Roaming\nvm

Edit the settings.txt and change from

> root: C:\Users\Light Seeker\AppData\Roaming\nvm
> path: C:\Program Files\nodejs

to

> root: C:\Users\LIGHTS~1\AppData\Roaming\nvm
> path: C:\Program Files\nodejs

references: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/168

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `settings.txt` to use the old [8.3 naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names).

For example, before:

```
root: C:\Program Files\nvm
path: C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

When changed this this, it works. After:

```
root: C:\Progra~1\nvm
path: C:\Progra~1\nodejs
```