# shwoing that my directory has not been found when running nvm use 16.16.0

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

C:\Users\RAJ KUMAR\Desktop\raj_kumar_sen_fw22_0218\unit-6>**nvm list**

*** 19.1.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
16.16.0**

C:\Users\RAJ KUMAR\Desktop\raj_kumar_sen_fw22_0218\unit-6>**nvm use 16.16.0**
*exit status 1: 'C:\Users\RAJ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

exit status 1: 'C:\Users\RAJ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

I'm getting this error in cmd gitbach and vscode's powershell because of there is space in the root directory I think? could you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got the solution to this problem actually the normal cmd's are not accessing the administrator account so we need to run the command `nvm use version` in the `administrator cmd`.
For that, we need to right-click on the cmd app and then run it as administrator and then use the command.

Comment: Yeah that is weird. this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in paths are tricky and should be avoided when possible. There's a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595618/nvm-windows-fails-when-the-user-profile-path-contains-a-space/62376230#62376230), or you could change your `nvm` version to 1.1.9, though that has some [tradeoffs](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/881#issuecomment-1375679018). Another option would be to run WSL and use Node from there (using nvm or n). The least brittle but most annoying solution would be to change your username to use an underscore instead of a space, but that might require updating paths in other parts of your code and system.